# Allow last UITableViewCell to scroll till first row

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Generally in UITableView last UITableViewCell is not allowed to scroll up, I want to allow last UITableViewCell till it reaches first row.

One way I know is to adding empty footer to UITableView, but I can not figure out how much space I need to give footer to allowing last row to scroll.

Edit : Adding empty footerview to UITableView did trick for me

Comment: add tablefotterview. calculate height like (screen height - your last cell height). and set height to its tablefotterview.

Comment: Can not find height of last cell as its calculated dynamically

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure for this but i think it may help depending up on the contentInset and if the last cell height is not known

```
  -(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
  {
     CGRect temrect=CGRectMake(0, scrollView.contentSize.height-3, scrollView.frame.size.width, 3);
    // here i am expecting the height of the last row is atleast 3 and 
     for (UIView *temv in scrollView.subviews)
      {
         if (CGRectIntersectsRect(temrect, temv.frame)) // check ing for intersection
          {

            CGFloat bottomInset = scrollView.frame.size.height - temv.frame.size.height;
              scrollView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0 , bottomInset, 0);
             break;
         }
    }
 }
```

Note: it does not apply if the table view frame height is greater than the table view contentsize. it applies only if the temrect parameters intersect with the cell

hope it helps

Comment: Will check this soon and revert

Answer (score 0):

Set `contentInsets`

```
CGFloat bottomInset = tableView.frame.size.height - heightOfLastCell;
tableView.contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0 , bottomInset, 0);
```

Comment: Can not find height of last cell in advance as its calculated dynamically

Comment: Do you calculate it yourself or have the auto layout calculates it for you?

Comment: Autolayout does it for me

Comment: @Undercover Developer is the above code working for you if the cell size in known?

Comment: @UndercoverDeveloper Also, do you just want to scroll the last cell to the top or you want to allow the user to scroll them to the top?

Comment: I want to allow user to scroll them to the top

Answer (score 0):

A simple one:

Create a variable of `UITableView` off set and reset when you want to scroll out.

A simple exmaple will demonstrate to you

```
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint  tblOffSet;

- (void) keyboardOpen:(UIView *)view {
    self.tblOffSet = self.tblView.contentOffset;
}

- (void) keyboardClose {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
        [self.tblView setContentOffset:self.tblOffSet];
    }];
}
```